# Align label on top and right on same line in Python with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to center a label in the center and one on the right on the same line. But the label in the center is giving me problems and it brings the label on the right down. How can I do that?

This is the code for label1

```
label1 = tk.Label(top_frame, text=current_time, font=(DEFAULT_FONT, 13), fg='#ffffff', bg='#ff0000')
label1.pack(side='top', anchor='n')
```

This is the code  for label 2

```
label2 = tk.Label(top_frame, text=percent, font=(DEFAULT_FONT, 13), fg='#ffffff', bg='#ff0000')
label2.pack(side='right', anchor='ne')
```

And this is what I get

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lw1y.png)

Comment: Try reverse the pack order.

Comment: @acw1668 It seems to have worked! I didn't think it was such a stupid thing

Comment: try to use grid  layout